# SQL MAX(col1, col2) with priorities

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to select row with MAX(val1) for each group.
If there is more than one row with equal val1 = MAX(val1) I need to select from them row with MAX(val2), etc.
In pseudo code it should be like this:

```
IF row1.val1 != row2.val1
    GET MAX(val1)
ELSE
    GET MAX(val2)
```

For example:

I have table `nums` with one `TEXT` column `name` and three `INTEGER` columns — `id`, `num1` and `num2` filled with values:

```
id name num1 num2
1 Name1 10 20
2 Name1 10 30
3 Name2 08 15
4 Name2 10 20
5 Name3 20 2
6 Name3 20 1
```

I need a query which will return me this:

```
2
4
5
```

It could be something like

```
SELECT id FROM nums GROUP BY name HAVING MAX(num1, num2)
```

but MAX(num1, num2) doesn't work.

I'm using sqlite3 module with python3.8.

Comment: Your query syntax is not correct. Please post some sample data and expected output.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai Posted sample data and expected output

Comment: HAVING requires you to create a true/false statement like "HAVING max(val1) > 3".  Since you don't know the max value in a single SQL, you're going to have to nest two SQLs, one to calculate the max value and the outer to compare and filter.  There are several ways to do this.

Comment: Look for correlated sub-queries and using MAX as a window function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to select row with MAX(val1) for each group. If there is more than one row with equal val1 I need to select from them row with MAX(val2)

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select n.*
from nums n
where n.num2 = (select max(n2.num2) from nums n2 where n2.num1 = n.num1);
```

Or a window function:

```
select n.*
from (select n.*,
             row_number() over (partition by num1 order by num2 desc) as seqnum
      from nums n
     ) n
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff Is window function better if I have more than two values?

Comment: @Ae_Mc These are the results of both queries: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=dcd506fb55189d1276ef62148dc83bf4 Do they return your expected results?

Comment: @Ae_Mc . . . Actually, the correlated subquery is often a little faster with an appropriate index, which in this case would be on `(num1, num2)`.  However, the window function also performs quite well.

Comment: @forpas Actually no, but it gave me an idea for true query: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=5de273e24472b0d6fcbeafb66d6dfb8c

Comment: @Ae_Mc this also has nothing to do with what you asked. Where is the requirement: "If there is more than one row with equal val1 I need to select from them row with MAX(val2)"?

Comment: @forpas Again: I need to get row with MAX(val1) in group or, if there's more than one row with equal val1 = MAX(val1) in group, get row with MAX(val2) in this group. Query with partition by works fine.

Comment: @Ae_Mc in your question there is only "with equal val1" and not "with equal val1= MAX(val1)". You accepted an answer that was wrong in any case and is still wrong after it was edited.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I'll edit question and answer.